How to automate the daily execution of a web scraping script on JupyterHub and VSCode?
I am relatively new to web scraping, and I am currently working on a Python script that I run in a JupyterHub environment integrated with VSCode. My goal is to optimize this script so that it runs automatically every day to collect data, while avoiding duplicate entries.
code here
import os
import random
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import datetime

# Function to create directories if needed
def create_directories():
    base_path = '/home/housnimzeali'  # Main directory
    directories = ['scraped_data', 'logs', 'scraped_files']  # List of directories to create

    # Create directories if necessary
    for directory in directories:
        directory_path = os.path.join(base_path, directory)
        if not os.path.exists(directory_path):
            os.makedirs(directory_path)
            print(f"Directory created: {directory_path}")
        else:
            print(f"Directory already exists: {directory_path}")

# Function for introducing a random delay
def random_sleep(min_seconds=1, max_seconds=3):
    delay = random.uniform(min_seconds, max_seconds)
    time.sleep(delay)

# Function to load scraped URLs
def load_scraped_urls(file_path):
    try:
        if pd.io.common.file_exists(file_path):
            df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
            return set(df['URL'].tolist())  # Returns a set of scraped URLs
        else:
            return set()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading scraped URLs: {e}")
        return set()

# Function to save scraped URLs
def save_scraped_urls(scraped_urls, file_path):
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(scraped_urls), columns=['URL'])
        df.to_excel(file_path, index=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error saving scraped URLs: {e}")

# Function to extract content, tags, and date from an article
def scrap_contents_tags_date(article_url, headers):
    try:
        response = requests.get(article_url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        main_section = soup.select_one('main#main')
        content_div = main_section.select_one('.content') if main_section else None
        content = ' '.join([element.get_text(strip=True) for element in content_div.find_all(True)]) if content_div else 'No Content'

        date_div = content_div.select_one('span.article-meta-date') if content_div else None
        date = date_div.get_text(strip=True) if date_div else 'No Date'

        tags_section = main_section.select_one('.outside-content-zone.below-content')
        tags_div = tags_section.select_one('p.tags') if tags_section else None
        tags = [a.get_text(strip=True) for a in tags_div.find_all('a')] if tags_div else []

        return content, tags, date
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return 'No Content', [], 'No Date'

# Function to export articles to an Excel file
def export_to_excel(articles, filename):
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame(articles)
        df.to_excel(filename, index=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error writing to file {filename}: {e}")

# Function to log processed files
def log_files(file_log):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    log_filename = f"/home/housnimzeali/logs/scraped_files_log_{today}.txt"
    with open(log_filename, 'w') as log_file:
        for file_name in file_log:
            log_file.write(f"{file_name}\n")

# Main scraping function
def scrape_article(url, file_log, scraped_urls):
    article_data = []
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
    try:
        page_count = 0
        while True:
            random_sleep(min_seconds=2, max_seconds=5)
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            container = soup.select_one('main#main')

            if not container:
                print(f"No content found for URL: {url}")
                return article_data

            article_section = container.select_one('div.posts.publishables-list-wrap.first-item-larger')
            if not article_section:
                print(f"No articles found in section for URL: {url}")
                return article_data

            for article in article_section.select('.row'):
                title_elem = article.select_one('h3 a')
                article_link = title_elem['href'] if title_elem else None
                title = title_elem.get_text(strip=True) if title_elem else 'No Title'
                summary_div = article.select_one('p.hidden-xs.item-desc')
                summary = summary_div.get_text(strip=True) if summary_div else 'No Summary'

                if article_link:
                    full_article_link = urljoin(url, article_link)

                    if full_article_link not in scraped_urls:
                        content, tags, date = scrap_contents_tags_date(full_article_link, headers)
                        article_data.append({
                            'Title': title,
                            'Date': date,
                            'Summary': summary,
                            'Content': content,
                            'Tags': ', '.join(tags) if tags else 'No Tags',
                            'Source': 'Medical_news',
                            'URL': full_article_link
                        })
                        scraped_urls.add(full_article_link)

            # Save extracted articles to a file
            if article_data:
                file_name = f'/home/housnimzeali/scraped_data/medical_news_{page_count + 1}.xlsx'
                export_to_excel(article_data, file_name)
                file_log.append(file_name)
                article_data.clear()

            # Find the link to the next page (ignore "Previous")
            next_page = soup.select_one('div.site-paging a:contains("Next")')

            if next_page and 'href' in next_page.attrs:
                url = urljoin(url, next_page['href'])
            else:
                print("No next page, scraping finished.")
                break

            page_count += 1

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error during scraping: {e}")
        return article_data

    return article_data

# Main function
def main():
    file_log = []  # List to track files
    scraped_urls = load_scraped_urls('/home/housnimzeali/scraped_urls.xlsx')  # Load already scraped URLs
    url = "https://www.news-medical.net/medical/news"  # Example URL to scrape
    articles = scrape_article(url, file_log, scraped_urls)
    print("Scraping complete.")

    # Save log of files and scraped URLs
    log_files(file_log)
    save_scraped_urls(scraped_urls, '/home/housnimzeali/scraped_urls.xlsx')

# Call the main function
main()


**Context:
**
I have set up a scraping script that collects and exports data to Excel files.
I want to schedule it for daily execution.
My script uses libraries such as requests, BeautifulSoup, and pandas.
I am also looking to ensure the script correctly handles duplicate entries by checking and storing scraped URLs.
**My Questions:
**
What is the best way to automate the daily execution of this script on a JupyterHub and VSCode environment?
Should I use a tool like cron on the server where JupyterHub is hosted, or are there specific solutions for Jupyter/VSCode?
What best practices would you recommend to ensure the script runs reliably when scheduled and to handle errors or interruptions?
How can I optimize duplicate management in successive scrapes to avoid unnecessary repetition of data?
Thank you for your advice and help.

Jupyter developed out of IPython Notebook which developed from IPython. The I there stands for interactive. It is more meant for interactive endeavors. You seem to  not be wanting to be working interactively and so you simply don't need Jupyter in this workflow. Just use Python and cron. You'd build in handling of errors and unnecessary repeating. Python as commands in the console or as a script is the traditional way of running Python.
